# "Blinky" using C++ condition_variable for interruptible delays

Tags: c++

A class stores the state of the program - ready or busy. An LED indicator shows a steady colour when ready, otherwise it blinks to indicate that the device is busy. I want the LED to "immediately" reflect changes in the program's state i.e. it should not attempt to finish its blink cycle when the state changes to ready.

A routine running in its own thread acts on this information as follows:

```cpp
using namespace std::chrono::literals;

// This runs in a thread ... only snippet given here 
while(!m_should_close) {
    if (!m_ready) {
        // Blink
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_needs_update_mtx);

        led_on();

        if(!m_needs_update_cv::wait_for(lk, 300ms, []{ return m_needs_update; })) continue;

        led_off();

        if(!m_needs_update_cv::wait_for(lk, 300ms, []{ return m_needs_update; })) continue;

    } else {
        // Steady on
        led_on();        
    }
}
```

The `m_needs_update` atomic_boolean is set to true to notify the blinker thread that a change has occurred to either `m_should_close` or `m_ready`, and `m_needs_update_cv` is of type `std::condition_variable`. I have two problems with my design:

1. It doesn't *feel* right. There's something about substituting those two delays with long lines of "jibberish" that feels convoluted.
2. The timer of effective period 600ms is not very accurate and is at the whim of Linux scheduling, contention etc.

Do you have any architectural advice? Thanks.

Comment: Is `m_needs_update` an atomic boolean? Because that might be a condition race.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I've edited but I don't see how that makes any contribution to answering the question.

Comment: It does not indeed contribute to directly answer the question. That's why it was a comment and not a posted answer. It was a remark, a small question that may help other answer your question. Also, not using an atomic boolean is a mistake that is usually seen. Even worse, some use volatile thinking it help with sychronisation.